# Create Temporary Function in Hive

Tags: sql, function, hive, temporary

i have a query like this

```
CREATE TEMPORARY MACRO AAA (input VARCHAR(16))
input||
SUBSTR(
LPAD(
(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(LPAD(input,16,0),15,1) = 1 THEN 2
WHEN SUBSTR(LPAD(input,16,0),15,1) = 2 THEN 4
WHEN SUBSTR(LPAD(input,16,0),15,1) = 3 THEN 6
WHEN SUBSTR(LPAD(input,16,0),15,1) = 4 THEN 8
WHEN SUBSTR(LPAD(input,16,0),15,1) = 5 THEN 10
WHEN SUBSTR(LPAD(input,16,0),15,1) = 6 THEN 1
WHEN SUBSTR(LPAD(input,16,0),15,1) = 7 THEN 3
WHEN SUBSTR(LPAD(input,16,0),15,1) = 8 THEN 5
WHEN SUBSTR(LPAD(input,16,0),15,1) = 9 THEN 7
ELSE 0
END) +
(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(LPAD(input,16,0),16,1) = 1 THEN 1
WHEN SUBSTR(LPAD(input,16,0),16,1) = 2 THEN 2
WHEN SUBSTR(LPAD(input,16,0),16,1) = 3 THEN 3
WHEN SUBSTR(LPAD(input,16,0),16,1) = 4 THEN 4
WHEN SUBSTR(LPAD(input,16,0),16,1) = 5 THEN 5
WHEN SUBSTR(LPAD(input,16,0),16,1) = 6 THEN 6
WHEN SUBSTR(LPAD(input,16,0),16,1) = 7 THEN 7
WHEN SUBSTR(LPAD(input,16,0),16,1) = 8 THEN 8
WHEN SUBSTR(LPAD(input,16,0),16,1) = 9 THEN 9
ELSE 0
END)
,3,0), 3, 1);
```

but I want to create a temporary function for hive.
What needs to be changed and what format is it in to create a temporary function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write your own UDF.

Ref : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HivePlugins

Once you have jar file with custom logic you can create function like below:

Tested in Hive version apache-hive-4.0.0-alpha-1

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION aa_fun as 'AAA' using jar 'hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/aaa_func.jar';

select aa_fun('fwfrgwre12a3') fun_res, AAA('fwfrgwre12a3') macro_res;

+----------------+----------------+
|    fun_res     |   macro_res    |
+----------------+----------------+
| fwfrgwre12a33  | fwfrgwre12a33  |
+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: i use hive through hue,
how to find out 'hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/aaa_func.jar' and change it in hue?

Comment: you need to create it. `hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/aaa_func.jar` was example.

Comment: I'm new to hive, do I have to use jar?
if so, how do you make it and what are the contents?
can't we just use the following format like CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION TES (input VARCHAR(16))

Comment: function in hive generally means using custom code using jar. what you are trying to do is candidate for macro

Comment: if I create a jar file, can I still use the sql file above and then save it with the jar extension or does it have to be changed from sql query to java code?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood the question but sql and java code are 2 different thing. I don't think there is any way to create jar from sql